# Authenticate users using AWS Cognito + Azure AD + Facebook

Tags: facebook, azure, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to develop a React application that will allow users to login with their Azure AD accounts and their Facebook accounts.

The first thing is that I didn't understand about the 2 tabs "User
   Pools and Federation Identities". Do I need both to get it done or
   just the User Pools is enough?

My goal is just the authentications. I don't want to allow users to access any AWS service. I just want the authentication token.

I already got the user logged in via facebook using the Federation Identities and the Facebook SDK, but I don't know how to keep the user data saved after getting the token from facebook auth. Also is it correct to use the facebook SDK or should I use Cognito to take care of all authentication methods for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do I need both to get it done or just the User Pools is enough?**
No. Userpool is more than enough if you just need authentication and do not need to use AWS services.

**I already got the user logged in via facebook using the Federation Identities and the Facebook SDK, but I don't know how to keep the user data saved after getting the token from facebook auth.**
What user data do you need to save. If you want User's profile data to be saved in Cognito, you need to use Cognito Userpool & not Federated Identities. Add Facebook directly to Userpool. Upon using Facebook login, a user is auto-created in the userpool based on all user data available in the token. See [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social.html#cognito-user-pools-social-facebook) doc on how to add Facebook to a userpool directly.

**Also is it correct to use the facebook SDK or should I use Cognito to take care of all authentication methods for me?**
Depends on your use-case. If you just want to add authentication to an app, the best way would be to Add Facebook to a Userpool directly, create an app client in the userpool for your application; enable Facebook for that app client & use Cognito Userpool's built-in UI to login using Facebook. This feature (built-in UI) is called App Integration. After successful Facebook login, a valid token will be sent to your app. Do note that the token sent to your app would be from Cognito.

Client--> Userpool built-in UI --> Redirect to Facebook --> Login using username +password --> Facebook sends its token to Cognito ( https://your-user-pool-domain/oauth2/idpresponse)-->Userpool vends its own token & redirects to the URL mentioned in the redirect_uri.

Comment: thanks mate, I got it now! And what about a mobile app? When you have like social media logins and you can't use the Cognito UI built-in. Should I use the Facebook SDK instead and then pass the data (tokens + user_data) to Cognito? I'm using react native btw

Comment: You can still use Userpool. If you want to have ur own UI, you can do so. Look at my answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035466/3479734