# AWS Cognito custom login ui

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, user-interface, authentication

I am currently integrating aws auth / auth ui into my android app , but i can't find way to use my custom login ui, instread of hosted one , i want to use my own layout, button etc . tried to dig into doc , nothing helped me .

Just to mention , i don't want to impleement my own auth for custom backend or anything else, just ui customization.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like more of a aws support forum question than a programming one.  But can you tell us if don't want to customize the hosted login, are you trying to integrate and existing flow with cognito?  If so, check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html

Comment: Thanks , i will post there too , no i don't want to use my own backend or something like that . currently i implemented google+ login , it's working fine , but it's using amazon's pre-defined  ui , button layout etc , i want to configure everything else .

Comment: Currently, the AWS Auth UI only supports minimal customization. You can change the font style and background color and enable background color for full screen or not. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in-customize.html

Comment: @Karthikeyan i've checked it out already , but there could be trick or something to avoid that .  but thanks for answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cognito Userpool's authorization endpoint and Android SDK to implement the same. For Userpool logins, build your custom UI and on login, use the Android SDK to sign in your users. For other providers liek Login with Google or Facebook, use the Authorization endpoint with the correct identity provider specified. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019504/cognito-user-pools-is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-sign-up-in-form-for-faceb/47035466#47035466) for login using third-party providers. For Android implementation, check out [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo) sample app (especially [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/052b348128aee536037f6a4cc4b190a636a50fe9/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo/app/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/youruserpools/MainActivity.java#L298) & AppHelper.java).