# Automatically add authenticated google user to cognito user pool through aws-amplify in angular?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, federated-identity

I am using AWS Cognito to authenticate my site's users through a Google Federated Identity. Everything seems to be working correctly, the correct tokens are returned (as far as I can tell), and the user seems to be authenticated. However, I cannot figure out how to add the Google user to my Cognito User pool automatically, and I haven't found any documentation that has given me the answer. Any ideas?

Here is my Angular code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
declare const gapi: any;
declare const AWS: any;

const config = Auth.configure({
        identityPoolId: environment.AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
        region: environment.AWS_REGION,
        userPoolId: environment.AWS_USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: environment.CLIENT_ID
    });

@Component({
    selector: 'authentication',
    templateUrl: './authentication.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./authentication.component.sass']
})

export class AuthenticationComponent implements OnInit {

    public auth2: any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.googleInit();
    }

    // called immediately, preps for the click of the google button
    googleInit() {
        // google's function to prep user
        gapi.load('auth2', () => {
            this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                access_type: "offline",
                client_id: environment.GOOGLE_ID,
                client_secret: environment.CLIENT_SECRET,
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                scope: 'profile email'
            });
            // calls this on sign in
            this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
        });
    }

    // once a user is in the pop up login window
    attachSignin(element) {
        this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
            // this part is called if they successfully sign in
            (googleUser) => {
                // stores the user's profile
                let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                this.getCreds(googleUser.getAuthResponse(), profile.getEmail(), profile.getName())
                // this is called if the sign in does not work or if they close the window or anything of that sort
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            });
    }

    getCreds(authResult: any, email: string, name: string) {
        Auth.federatedSignIn('google', {
            token: authResult.id_token,
            expires_at: authResult.expires_at
           }, {email, name}
           ).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            });

        this.queryAWS(authResult.id_token);
    }

    queryAWS(id_token: any) {
         AWS.config.region = environment.AWS_REGION;
         AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
             IdentityPoolId: environment.AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
             Logins: { "accounts.google.com": id_token }
        });
        AWS.config.credentials.get(err => {
            if (!err) {
                Cookie.set('awsAuthenticated', 'true', 7);
                sessionStorage.setItem('expireTime', AWS.config.credentials['expireTime']);
            }
            else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: User pool and identity pool is different.  `Auth.federatedSignIn` will reflect in identity pool, not at the user pool. As far as I know, there is no interface at amplify that will transfer user between.

Comment: Good to know. Is there a particular library you would recommend instead? And if I authenticate a user directly into the user pool will that still reflect in the identity pool?

Comment: I do not know. 4 months ago I searched for it. but could not. 
No.
I have done it without any library. Please follow this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019504/cognito-user-pools-is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-sign-up-in-form-for-faceb/47035466#47035466