# is it possible to change the AWS cognito hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

can we change the AWS Cognito hosted UI HTML?
I have created my own login page and I want to use that as the hosted UI for login functionality.

I have tried for CSS customization it is possible but not able to change the HTML of the AWS Cognito hosted UI. I have also tried to reach the AWS support team but not got any response.

thanks for help?

Comment: The short answer is: yes, you can, link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-ux.html

Comment: As you have already created your own login page, you can try to implement like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019504/cognito-user-pools-is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-sign-up-in-form-for-faceb

Answer (score 6):

One thing we did at a company (we had significantly more than a million monthly logins) was to host our own OAuth2 OIDC server and use the (serverside) Cognito Admin API as a user management system.

The Admin API lets you create, update, delete users as well as mint tokens and all of that good stuff.

When a user would log into our custom login front-end, we would send the credentials to our identity server, which would then try log in with Cognito via the admin API. Cognito would send back a JWT which we would essentially throw away and reissue a new token from our identity server for the user session.

This gets complex when you start trying to manage things like resetting the password where you need the cognito token and not your token.

Additionally, we found that Cognito had a bunch of embedded functionality that you cannot reconfigure. We had to migrate our users from our existing user stores into Cognito and we decided to trigger a migration when a user logged in. We did this because we don't have the user passwords in plaintext, only when they log in so if we were to automatically dump everyone into cognito we would have had to force everyone to reset their passwords.

It turns out that Cognito has a built in email verification system (send a code and all that) - awesome but when you use the admin API and add a user that already has a verified email address, it still dispatches the verification email.

We had to set up lambdas to intercept the email and check if the user has a certain tag. It was a nightmare.

Anyway, Auth0 is more expensive but easier as everything is customisable. Same with Okta.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more than CSS customization, you’ll have to *host* your own login page. It would be hard for Cognito to let you replace or inject your own HTML, since the login page is [quite complicated](https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/replace-cognito-hosted-ui-d7619d037036):

> The Cognito Hosted UI is far more than a UI. It’s a full blown OAuth server, backed by the Cognito API.

**If** you really want to do it, you can host your login page somewhere (consider an [S3 static website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)). Make sure it implements your [desired auth flow](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/login-with-aws-cognito.html) correctly, and have it redirect to your site on successful auth just like Cognito does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible to customize the page elements surrounding the Cognito UI using the amplify SDK but this would require that you handle certain things that Cognito already handles by default. See here https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/q/framework/react a couple of other popular frameworks are supported

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloudflare, you can try using this app to customize **hosted Cognito UI**.
https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/add-html

For this to work, you will need to have your own domain for Cognito.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Better way to achieve this would be to create your own UI with customisations, host the static contents to S3 bucket and then configure it with cognito.